# How to update tables with duplicate keys in sql?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, insert-into

How can I update a table that accept duplicate keys in SQL?

I was using Insert Into on Duplicate Key,  but for a new requirement I need rows with duplicate keys.

How do I achieve the same behavior that   Insert Into on Duplicate Key statement.

Thanks

Comment: I'm confused, can you provide your table structure?

Comment: What do you mean by duplicate key? Like 2 primary keys (or I guess technically it's a combined key)?

Comment: You cant, you can either have unique keys, or not have unique keys.  On Duplicate only works on unique keys (when a duplicate is inserted it triggers an update instead).  So if you allow duplicates there is no way to trigger an update.  In other words you either have unique keys or you don't.  If you don't then it makes no sense to update when an insert is done using the same key if it's not unique.

Comment: There must be something different between the data on each row. Use that different value in a [`where` clause](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Where_(SQL)).

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix I thought keys were always unique (in MySQL, anyway)..

Comment: I should mention you can use On Duplicate for a Primary key (surrogate key) for the table, provided it is unique.  A surrogate key is a key that has no relationship to the actual data in the row, a common example is an Auto Increment ID.  The Auto increment value has no relation to what is in the row.  If you don't have one, you should.  A unique key is some piece of unique data embedded in the row, such as an email or user login etc.

Comment: @Chipster - it's a matter of terminology as you can have non-unique "Indexes" which some people simply call Keys..

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix Got you. In other words, it's not technically a key as in Primary Key.

Comment: Right it's just a unique index, but even look at how arrays are refereed to, you can have an array "key" or an array "index" and they are used somewhat interchangeable, like method and function, it depends on the context.  Little [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surrogate_key) on surrogate keys.

Comment: Really without more information on the schema and the data that needs to go in there, it's not answerable.

Comment: You need a separate table for the unique keys, each key should and must be unique in that table. You need to reference to this table using a foreign key from the other tables where a duplicate key is possible)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should never have duplicate keys. It is against the structure of a relational database. If you need to do something like this, then you need to redesign your database or add a new table with the data you want to duplicate but apply it to many that hold unique data.